# User defined type including itself

Tags: database, cassandra, user-defined-types, nosql

Oke, maybe I am trying something stupid here and the errors I get already gave me a hint that I am. But is it possible to have a user defined type within itself in C*?

So this would be the result.

```sql
CREATE TYPE udt (
    id uuid,
    child frozen <udt>,
    childeren list <frozen <udt>>
);

InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unknown type space.udt"
```

I can imagine that the type has to be declared. Before it can be used inside itself. So naturally I'd try something like this.

```sql
CREATE TYPE udt (
    id uuid
);

ALTER TYPE udt ADD child frozen <udt>;
--ALTER TYPE udt ADD children list <frozen <udt>>;

InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot add new field child of type space.udt to type space.udt as this would create a circular reference"
```

This error message is introduced due to [CASSANDRA-10339](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10339) which was reported after this post [Cassandra 2.1: Recursion by nesting UDT's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29037733/cassandra-2-1-recursion-by-nesting-udts)

In a relational database I understand this is a problem but why can't C* handle this. The data is not referencing itself in anyway so I would expect that "circular referencing" is happening within C* itself. But why is it a problem here? It only describes how the data should be structured. To me it would be like a json object where the object structure is repeated within itself.

If somebody would ask me this question I'd probably respond with "Why would you want this?"

So a real world example would be a kind of decision tree. So I'd have a table `questionaire` that has a user defined type `question`. This question holds the questions to ask next. This could be two attributes, in case of yes and no kind of questions, of type `question`. This hopefully clarifies what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Cassandra does not support such operations then probably you would like to store your data structure as a json string within a regular text column (instead of UDT).

Comment: If the number of chained questions is theoretically infinite as it seems to be, then this kind of storage could be very inefficient. Besides, two questions could lead to the same next question, at least in theory; in this case, storing duplicates in a json string is also inefficient.

Comment: I disagree that this aproach would require storing duplicated data within a single json. Storing ids as reference to other questions should be enough. So infinite chains of questions are also possible in this representation.

Comment: This was one of the alternatives I came up with. But the question is more about why it is not possible in C*. Still I do not see how, wether in udt's or json, the data can be infinite. I mean I understand that it is not finite but storing/handeling infinite data will not be possible in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Circular UDT references are not possible with Cassandra, see [CASSANDRA-10339](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10339) for some explanation.

You should model a question as a table, not a UDT. Granted, you would have to issue a query each time to get the next question, but I don't see any other alternative.

Comment: If I understood Cassandra correctly this is kind of an anti-pattern